# Azure - Storage Account/ARM Issue

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-storage-account

Pretty new to Azure and struggling with creating a VM from an existing vhd. I get the following error when executing `New-AzureQuickVM -ImageName MyVirtualHD.vhd -Windows -ServiceName test`:

`CurrentStorageAccountName is not accessible. Ensure that current storage account is accessible and the same location or affinity group as your cloud service.`

`Select-AzureRMSubscription` does not return anything for the CurrentStorageAccount property. `Get-AzureRMStorageAccount` does list my storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Azure has two deployment models: "Classic" and "Resource Manager" (ARM). You're not seeing your ARM-created storage accounts because you're using classic-mode powershell commands to list storage accounts, and your storage accounts were created with the (newer) Resource Management API (and the classic API will only list storage accounts created with the "classic" management API).

Your example shows you mixing the two types. (also - don't worry about resource groups in this context - that's not your issue - resource groups are unrelated for this).

Once you select your subscription (via `Select-AzureRmSubscription`), and then `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount`, you should see all of your newly created storage accounts.

Also: `Set-AzureSubscription` does something different - it's for altering subscription properties. You want `Select-...` for selecting the default subscription to work with.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm still having the issue of no CurrentStorageAccount property when using Select-AzureRMSubscription. Ultimately I want to be able to call New-AzureQuickVM and pass it the name of an existing vhd but I can't do that when I can't see the storage account. Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to set the CurrentStorageAccount property by using Set-AzureRMCurrentStorage. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be an ARM equivalent of New-AzureQuickVM so I'm still looking for a way to create a new VM based on an existing vhd.

Comment: Dave - one option for you might be to use a json template for creating the VM - check out: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-simple-linux and you can see how to deploy with PowerShell in the root of the repo